# MYSQL update one field in all rows that match a second field if third field in any row contains a value

Tags: mysql

```
OrderNumber    SKU    IsFBA    Description
123456         RED5            Product Payment
123456         RED5            commission
123456         RED5            FBA Fees
234567         RED5            Product Payment
234567         RED5            commission
345678         RED5            Product Payment
345678         RED5            commission
```

I would like to create an SQL statement that updates IsFBA = yes
in All OrderNumbers that have the same orderNumber of any row where the Description like '%FBA%'

In other words:
Line 3, 'Description' contain "FBA" (LIKE'%FBA%').   I would like it to update 'IsFBA' to yes in all the the other rows that have the same OrderNumber as this line.

So my result is:

```
OrderNumber    SKU    IsFBA    Description
123456         RED5   yes      Product Payment
123456         RED5   yes      commission
123456         RED5   yes      FBA Fees
234567         RED5            Product Payment
234567         RED5            commission
345678         RED5            Product Payment
345678         RED5            commission
```

I can easily do this with PHP looping through the database but wonder if there is a mySQL statement that can do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, havent tested though.

```
UPDATE MyTable m1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT OrderNumber
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Description LIKE '%FBA%'
   GROUP BY OrderNumber
) m2 ON m1.OrderNumber = m2.OrderNumber
SET IsFBA = 'yes'
```

It's slightly better than using `IN`.

Comment: This worked.  It was really slow, but that could be my (lack of)  indexing on that field.  (14000 rows)

Comment: @Kevin glad to help. Try adding index on Description & OrderNumber. You can also remove the `GROUP BY` part which might speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `OrderNumber` in a subquery like this:

```
UPDATE table SET IsFBA = true WHERE OrderNumber IN (SELECT DISTINCT OrderNumber FROM `table` WHERE Description LIKE '%FBA%')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
Update yourTable SET IsFBA = true WHERE OrderNumber IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT OrderNumber FROM yourTable WHERE Description LIKE '%FBA%') AS A
```

Comment: I get an error on this: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'yourTable' for update in FROM clause  (changing 'yourTable' for my table name).  Splitting the two parts works fine.

Comment: I get the same error.  It makes sense, is elegant and seems like it should have worked.   I tried the inner join approach by GGio which worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table 
SET IsFBA = true
WHERE OrderNumber IN (
                    SELECT OrderNumber
                    FROM table
                    WHERE Description LIKE '%FBA%')
```